# Manually boot Linux, how to pass initrd, dtb, command line to Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, bootloader

I am trying to boot ARMv8 Linux totally manually, which means there is NO bootloader at all in hand. I can load the kernel image, initrd and fdt to memory, then 'jump' to the kernel entry point to boot it.
But I don't know how to tell the kernel where is the initrd or dtb, and what is the kernel command line.. :-(.
So the question on ARMv8 Linux is what is the way to pass info of initrd, dtb and command line to the kernel, without using bootloader ?

The uboot code of bootm for ARM is as follows (arch/arm/lib/bootm.c),

```
    if (CONFIG_IS_ENABLED(OF_LIBFDT) && images->ft_len)
        r2 = (unsigned long)images->ft_addr;
    else
        r2 = gd->bd->bi_boot_params;

    if (!fake) {
#ifdef CONFIG_ARMV7_NONSEC
        if (armv7_boot_nonsec()) {
            armv7_init_nonsec();
            secure_ram_addr(_do_nonsec_entry)(kernel_entry,
                              0, machid, r2);
        } else
#endif
            kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
    }
#endif
```

With fdt loaded into memory, the r2 is fdt memory address.
The entry point of Linux kernel (5.19.9) of ARM64 is as follows (arch/arm64/kernel/head.S),

```
/*
 * Preserve the arguments passed by the bootloader in x0 .. x3
 */
SYM_CODE_START_LOCAL(preserve_boot_args)
    mov x21, x0             // x21=FDT

    adr_l   x0, boot_args           // record the contents of
    stp x21, x1, [x0]           // x0 .. x3 at kernel entry
    stp x2, x3, [x0, #16]

    dmb sy              // needed before dc ivac with
                        // MMU off

    add x1, x0, #0x20           // 4 x 8 bytes
    b   dcache_inval_poc        // tail call
SYM_CODE_END(preserve_boot_args)
```

It seemd that kernel thinks X0 is the address of fdt (or boot args).
So what register is used to pass FDT to kernel in the bootup ?

Comment: it is somewhat trivial, set a simple structure, point at it with a register, call the entry point to the kernel.  You can look at the lines of code used on the raspberry pi as an easy way to see this (a chunk of that code is there to "sort the cores" and park them since they all come it of reset at the same time on that platform.

Comment: Study **Documentation/arm/booting.rst** or **Documentation/arm64/booting.rst** for the requirements.  BTW **initrd** is semi-obsolete, replaced by **initramfs**.  The kernel command line is contained in the **dtb**.

Comment: The document os booting.rst seems old, I am not sure if it is correct for current ARMv8 platforms, and it does NOT say how to pass kernel command line to the kernel. And I am not sure that 'kernel command line is contained in the dtb', I dumped the dtb in my ARMv8 Linux, but did not find the command line.

Comment: @old_timer, I am pretty new to ARM, could you help with some links/samples of raspberry PI on the register usage in kernel bringup??

Comment: @sawdust, the SO question has more details on command line in dtb. And i checked the dtb in my ARMv8 Linux, there is bootargs section. But the content is different from the one bootloader sets up. And I checked arch/arm64/kernel/head.S, it seemed that dtb is passed to kernel within R0, not in the R2 in kernel document.

Comment: there is a baremetal forum at the raspberry pi site, and in there are folks that have disassembled the small bit of code the pi folks use.   I would argue, if you want to use that as a reference then ask this question there.   You should also be able to find out how all this works from u-boot and I forget the other popular bootloader.